ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket on Macos 10.13
When I start the mysql server the following happens:
But then the lights turn red which means the mysql server stopped running.  How can I get the mysql server to keep running after I turn it on?

#######UPDATE
I read that if I type in
ps -ef | grep mysql

which outputs
501 72931 70523   0  2:14AM ttys000    0:00.01 grep mysql

that I should then input
sudo kill -9 [PID]
However when I replaced [PID] with all three of the numbers above plus a combination of a three numbers I get either 'illegal process id' or 'no such process'
#######UPDATE
Using deceze's advice I'd looked in the log and found that the keyring file is throwing an error and it looks like it is missing in my computer and I cannot find it.  I just download Mysql, maybe I downloaded the wrong kind of Mysql except that there were 5 versions and I couldn't figure out which one to install.  Anyway here is the error message
024-05-07T05:56:52.406753Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010901] [Server] Can't open shared library '/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/keyring_file.so' (errno: 2 dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/keyring_file.so, 0x0002): tried: '/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/keyring_file.so' (no such file)).
2024-05-07T05:56:52.406788Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010736] [Server] Couldn't load plugin named 'keyring_file' with soname 'keyring_file.so'.

But as you can see the keyring file does not exist in the specified folder.
#######UPDATE
redownloading mysql didn't work.  there is only one download that works with my computer.  the keyring file is still missing.  I think I should just probably give up on mysql and try sql.  All I'm trying to do is convert a sql file into db anyway and I have only found instructions for how to do that with mysql.  so if anyone knows the answer to this question I can ditch mysql
How to convert .sql file to tables in mysql db


You need to look at the logs of MySQL somewhere, it'll probably tell you about something that's wrong.

Your ps -ef | grep mysql only outputs the grep command you're running, not your actual server. That's why you can't kill it, since it's the wrong process to begin with, and by the time you're trying to kill it it doesn't exist anymore.

You should put the error message you've discovered front and center in your question title and as the main question in your question, so people who know about it can find and answer your question better.

I needed to change the configurations to the following, that solved the problem.

you can see this answer mysql bugs link
Daniel Fischer suggest that: To get it to start, please disable the "Keyring Data File" option in the preference pane, or remove the two keyring lines from the launchd plist manually.
【disable the "Keyring Data File" option in the preference pane】 is useful to me，hope it will be useful to you

Make sure you install 8.4 first and then re-run 9.0>

What do you mean by "re-run"? The question doesn't mention MySQL 9 anywhere, it wasn't even released when the OP posted this
